# How to create a file when the file is not exist in WinRT?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

**What I want**
open a file if it exists, create it if it not exists

**What I code**

```
        try
        {
            return await folder.GetFileAsync(fileName);

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException )
        {
            StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName);
            return file;
        }
```

**What the error**
Cannot await in the body of a catch clause

How to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just call `CreateFileAsync` and specify [`OpenIfExists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.creationcollisionoption)?

> Create the new file or folder with the desired name, or returns an existing item if a file or folder already exists with that name.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you do not want to change the code much. You can set a flag `exceptionOccurred = true` in catch flag and then write the code to create the file after the catch clause if the flag is true.